# Openpyxl: switching between formulas and computed values at the worksheet level?

Tags: openpyxl

I'm currently aggregating workbooks where I can get away with just copying the calculated results for about 80% of the worksheets. However, I need to preserve the formulas for the remaining sheets.

I'm currently having to read each workbook in twice, creating separate workbook objects for ones with formulas and ones with calculated values:

```
calcualted_wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
formula_wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
```

This seems very inefficient, and I am wondering, **Is there a way a way to switch between calculated and formula values at the worksheet level?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's a global setting when reading the workbook. Easy enough to have two workbooks one of which is read-only and data-only and the other is editable.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I was just trying to consider the clients speed / memory requirements, as the script will be aggregation over 50 large workbooks to aggregate at a once.

Comment: read-only mode is your friend there. Don't know your code but you're unlikely to need to have them all editable at once, but if you do you'll need lots of memory.

Comment: I am still learning so I am actually manipulating each sheet into a simpler format before copying over, which allows me to reuse the same code, but I'll fix it in V2 as I get better at handling irregular sheets, merged cells, and formatting.